# Adding host name to /etc/hosts in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

Is there an easy way to add DHCP issued IP address and host name of a Linux machine in /etc/hosts at system startup automatically?

Background:
My Linux machine has a host name in /etc/hostname and it won't resolve to anything when I ping. I manually added my host name and IP address in /etc/hosts for one my network related Java programs to work.

Comment: If you want DNS resolution, that's usually a part of the DHCP server configuration -- to shuttle the info to the DNS server.

Comment: Its not a true DNS resoultion. I want to use a hostname and will be able to ping from the same machine using that hostname (not from outside that machine). That's why I am relying on /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dhcpcd has a [`-c/--script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/dhcpcd-bin.8.html) option to run an external script anytime it configures or brings up an interface. You can use this to manually update the hosts file with the configured hostname.

Comment: I have a process 'dhcpcpclient3'. Is this the same as dhcpd? If so, where do I change the configuration to specify a script? Thanks.

Comment: `/etc/dhcp3` has all its config files. The -c option is for when you invoke it directly from the command line. For config-file based changes, it'd be the `script` option in the main dhclient.conf

Comment: Right now 'script' section in /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf is commented out. I will pass my own script there to update /etc/hosts. Is there any relation between this 'script' and /sbin/dhclient-script? Does the 'script' entry in /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf need to follow any special convention or is it just any shell script? Thanks.

Comment: The script should be just a regular shell script, and its arguments would be the data coming out of the new dhcp setup. As for the rest, not sure - never needed to have a dhcp override script before. My /sbni/dhclient-script seems to be part of the initial dhcp setup and has a bunch of helper scripts - not sure where it's called from, though.

Comment: I finally found a good way to do this. dhcp exit hook. I wrote a script and put it in the exit-hooks directory and that got executed after the dhcp lease. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu, add an executable file into the `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory. Files in this directory get executed after the network manager configures a network interface.

You may adapt the following script :

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
    exit 0
fi

myHostName=`hostname`

# Remove current line with hostname at the end of line ($ means end of line)
sed -i '/'$myHostName'$/ d' /etc/hosts

ipaddr=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "$ipaddr $myHostName" >>/etc/hosts
```

Comment: I have one question this will working for which Linux version Can We create multi version script for each Linux/Mac/Windows System ?
It is better Idea to do for Cross Platform.

Comment: I managed to simplify the ipaddr assertion using the following one-liner: `ifconfig | awk -F" +|:" '/inet addr/ && $4 != "127.0.0.1" {print $4}'`

Answer (score 1):

Use [avahi](http://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) (which should be on your distro repositories), then you can

```
$ ping youhostname.local
```

Answer (score 1):

I took what @Markus did and put it into a normal script. This works on my Fedora 20 box:

```
#!/bin/sh

MYHOST=firtree

echo "before:"
cat /etc/hosts

# Remove current line with hostname at the end of line ($ means end of line)
sed -i '/'$MYHOST'$/ d' /etc/hosts

echo "after remove: "
cat /etc/hosts

IPADDR=$(ifconfig | awk -F" +|:" '/inet addr/ && $4 != "127.0.0.1" {print $4}')
echo "$IPADDR $MYHOST" >>/etc/hosts

echo "ip: " $IPADDR
echo "final: "
cat /etc/hosts
```

This does have to be run as root, and probably should go in an init.d folder.

Comment: Not good, ungrepping 127 may drop the actual address if it contains 127 (for example 192.168.4.127), better rephrase or use this one-liner: `ifconfig | awk -F" +|:" '/inet addr/ && $4 != "127.0.0.1" {print $4}'`

Answer (score 0):

From

```
ipaddr=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}’)
host=`hostname`
fhost=`hostname -f`

echo "$ipaddr $fhost $host" >> /etc/hosts

cat /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this script to set my hostname (existing one) + dynamic IP to `/etc/hosts` file :

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0| grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}')
hn=$(hostname)
hnd=$(hostname -f)
sed -i '2s/.*/'$ipaddr'  '$hnd'   '$hn'/' /etc/hosts
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just unique command bellow:

```
sudo sh -c -e "echo '$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') youhostname.local' >> /etc/hosts"
```